# How to add data to a list inside a class model from firebase. Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, drop-down-menu, flutter-layout

I have a class model "Repository" which contains a List.
This List contains some Data..like this..

```
import 'state_model.dart';

class Repository {
  dynamic getAll() => _india.length;

  getLocalByState(String state) => _india
      .map((map) => StateModel.fromJson(map))
      .where((item) => item.state == state)
      .map((item) => item.lgas)
      .expand((i) => i)
      .toList();

  List<String> getStates() => _india
      .map((map) => StateModel.fromJson(map))
      .map((item) => item.state)
      .toList();

  List<Map> _india= [
    {
      "state": "Kerala",
      "alias": "adamawa",
      "lgas": [
        "Kannur",
        "Kochi",
        "Kasargode",
      ]
    },
    {
      "state": "Karanataka",
      "alias": "akwa_ibom",
      "lgas": ["Banglore", "Mysore", "HasanNagar"]
    },
    {
      "state": "Tamil Nadu",
      "alias": "ogun",
      "lgas": [
        "Chennai",
        "Vellore",
        "Coimbatore",
        "Selam",
      ]
    },
  ];
}
```

what I want is to add data from a firebase data. which contains the same JSON data as in the above list.
With the above Data, I created a custom dropDown Button.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:grocbstoremanager/repository.dart';

class CustomDropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function func1;
  final Function func2;
  final String item;
  final bool edit;
  final String item2;

  const CustomDropDown(
      {this.func1, this.func2, this.item, this.edit, this.item2});

  @override
  _CustomDropDownState createState() => _CustomDropDownState();
}

class _CustomDropDownState extends State<CustomDropDown> {
  List<String> _states = ["Choose Category"];
  List<String> _lgas = ["Choose .."];
  String _selectedState = "Choose Category";
  String _selectedLGA = "Choose ..";

  Repository repo = Repository();
  
  void getdata() {
    Firestore.instance.collection("Categories").getDocuments().then((value) {
      print(value.documents.last.data);
      _states.add(value.documents.last.data["state"]);
      print((value.documents.last.data["lgas"]));
      _lgas.add((value.documents.last.data["lgas"][0]));
    });
    print("added data wow...");
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getdata();
    
    _states = List.from(_states)..addAll(repo.getStates());
    super.initState();
  }

  void _onSelectedState(String value) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedLGA = "Choose ..";
      _lgas = ["Choose .."];
      _selectedState = value;
      _lgas = List.from(_lgas)..addAll(repo.getLocalByState(value));
      widget.func1(_selectedState);
    });
  }

  void _onSelectedLGA(String value) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedLGA = value;
      widget.func2(_selectedLGA);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 49,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            flex: 3,
            child: FormField(builder: (FormFieldState<String> state) {
              return InputDecorator(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0))),
                child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                  child: DropdownButton<String>(
                    isExpanded: true,
                    items: _states.map((String dropDownStringItem) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: dropDownStringItem,
                        child: Text(dropDownStringItem),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (value) => _onSelectedState(value),
                    value: _selectedState,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 10,
          ),
          Flexible(
            flex: 2,
            child: FormField(builder: (FormFieldState<String> state) {
              return InputDecorator(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0))),
                child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                  child: DropdownButton<String>(
                    isExpanded: true,
                    items: _lgas.map((String dropDownStringItem) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: dropDownStringItem,
                        child: Text(dropDownStringItem),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (value) => _onSelectedLGA(value),
                    value: _selectedLGA,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

With the above code, the dropdown not showing any dynamic data which i passed through the firebase data..
all it shows is the data I already given..
I tried printing the list...
it shows data included from firebase..
but it's not showing on the screen

I tried calling setState().. still no use...

My StateModel

```
class StateModel {
  String state;
  String alias;
  List<String> lgas;

  StateModel({this.state, this.alias, this.lgas});

  StateModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    state = json['state'];
    alias = json['alias'];
    lgas = json['lgas'].cast<String>();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['state'] = this.state;
    data['alias'] = this.alias;
    data['lgas'] = this.lgas;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In flutter when you want to update the UI with some new data, you need to call the `setState((){})` method in the `State` class of the `StatefulWidget`. This tells the framework that the widget’s state has changed and that the widget should be redrawn.

From the flutter docs [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive)

> A stateful widget is implemented by two classes: a subclass of StatefulWidget and a subclass of State.
> The state class contains the widget’s mutable state and the widget’s build() method.
> When the widget’s state changes, the state object calls setState(), telling the framework to redraw the widget.

So in your code above, when you receive the data from the Firebase FireStore and add it inside the corresponding `List`, you need to call the `setState((){})` method after adding the data to the lists.

So your `getData()` should look like:

```
void getdata() {
    Firestore.instance.collection("Categories").getDocuments().then((value) {
      setState((){
         _states.add(value.documents.last.data["state"]);
         _lgas.add((value.documents.last.data["lgas"][0]));
      });

      print((value.documents.last.data["lgas"]));
      print(value.documents.last.data);
    });
  }
```

**P.S.:**
Also, calling `setState((){})` rebuilds the widget, to update the UI according to the data present. The data is already added in the list when you do the `.add()`, that is the reason you can see the new data in the list, but the UI is still showing the old data because the widget has not been rebuilt to show the updated data.